# Validation before posting a ledger journal

Tags: axapta, dynamics-ax-2012, x++, dynamics-ax-2012-r3

I need to check if some conditions are met before posting a ledger journal, and if not cancel the posting process.

Should i add a code section in class `LedgerJournalCheckPost` method: `validate`() ?

My tests are working, and this method is called both when validating or posting so it solves my case.

But is there another approach to accomplish such a thing?

Comment: ...And ensure other journals that share the same classes don't (or do!) call your validation method...  While tests in the general journal may pass, should the acquisition of fixed assets also call the validation class for example?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends what you're doing. The `validate(...)` method at `\Classes\LedgerJournalCheckPost\validate(...)` is used for validating the journal itself.  Such as, has it already been posted? Is there a journal number?

The `checkJournal(...)` method at `\Classes\LedgerJournalCheckPost\checkJournal` (and various methods called from this method) is used for checking the data in the journal.

You should examine this method to see what logically makes the most sense for you.

You'd probably log posting errors like this too:
`ok = ledgerPostingMessageCollection.logCheckFailed(...)`

Just look in that method to follow their pattern.

Comment: Thanks, I think checkJournal method is more suited for my task .. i was close this time :)